# Calling SQL Server stored procedure from C# via ado.net times out

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net, .net-2.0

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server, which runs immediately from Management Studio.

When calling the stored procedure from code, with exact the same parameters, it times out.

The stored procedure accepts many parameters, that most have NULL as default value. I have tried assigning parameters to the `SqlCommand` object with a number of ways:

- Not adding parameters for null values
- Adding parameters for null values and pass as a value DBNull.Value
- Using SQLCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters and assigning only the non null values

Sp takes among others 2 `datetime` parameters. When the range of these dates is small the query runs, but for larger ranges (3 months or so), when I try to execute the `ExecuteReader` method I get a `SqlException - Timeout expired`. The rows to be returned are not much (around 3500).

In an effort to see what's happening with the processes, I run the following query when the `ExecuteReader` method starts to run

```
SELECT st.text AS [SQL Text],
       w.session_id, 
       w.wait_duration_ms,
       w.wait_type, w.resource_address, 
       w.blocking_session_id, 
       w.resource_description 
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS w
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON w.session_id = c.session_id 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle)) AS st 
WHERE w.session_id > 50
  AND w.wait_duration_ms > 0
```

and I get results like the following. Is it normal?

```
SQL Text    session_id  wait_duration_ms    wait_type   resource_address    blocking_session_id resource_description
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVoucherJobs]...  64  23993   CXPACKET    0x000000008012A870  64  exchangeEvent id=port801283d0 nodeId=0
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVoucherJobs]...  64  15  IO_COMPLETION   NULL    NULL    NULL
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVoucherJobs]...  64  15  IO_COMPLETION   NULL    NULL    NULL
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVoucherJobs]...  64  2121    CXPACKET    0x000000008012BE60  64  exchangeEvent id=port801283d0 nodeId=0
```

If instead of calling the stored procedure, I run the query through setting the `CommandText` to sp's body it runs immediately. This my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVoucherJobs] 
    @sUsrClientCode NVARCHAR(50),
    @dFr DATETIME = NULL,
    @dTo DATETIME = NULL,
    @sVchSerial NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @sConName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @sJobOrderId NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @sUsrName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @bJobClosed BIT = NULL,
    @bJobCanceled BIT = NULL,
    @bCount BIT = 0,
    @bGTCostCenter BIT = 0 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @bCount = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @bGTCostCenter = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT CASE WHEN sfVchBelongsTo IS NULL THEN sVchSerial ELSE sfVchBelongsTo END, Jobs.*,
                nkVch, sVchConName, sVchConAddress, sVchConCity, sVchConTel, sVchConZip, sVchDest, sVchCourier,
                sVchSerial, nVchPieces, cVchWeight, sVchDesc, sVchAdditional, cVchTotal, sVchStatus,
                sVchSubCode, sfVchBelongsTo, cVchInsAmount, nfVchJob, sUsrName
            FROM Jobs
            INNER JOIN Users ON nfJobUser = nkUsr
            INNER JOIN Vouchers ON nfVchJob = nkJob
            WHERE nfVchLinkedTo IS NULL AND
            sUsrClientCode = @sUsrClientCode AND
            (@dFr IS NULL OR dJob >= @dFr) AND
            (@dTo IS NULL OR dJob <= @dTo) AND
            (@sVchSerial IS NULL OR sVchSerial LIKE (@sVchSerial + '%')) AND
            (@sConName IS NULL OR sVchConName LIKE (@sConName + '%')) AND
            (@sJobOrderId IS NULL OR sJobOrderId LIKE (@sJobOrderId + '%')) AND
            (@sUsrName IS NULL OR sUsrName = @sUsrName) AND
            (@bJobClosed IS NULL OR bJobClosed = @bJobClosed) AND
            (@bJobCanceled IS NULL OR bJobCanceled = @bJobCanceled)
            ORDER BY 1, nkJob
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT CASE WHEN sfVchBelongsTo IS NULL THEN sVchSerial ELSE sfVchBelongsTo END, Jobs.*,
                nkVch, sVchConName, sVchConAddress, sVchConCity, sVchConTel, sVchConZip, sVchDest, sVchCourier,
                sVchSerial, nVchPieces, cVchWeight, sVchDesc, sVchAdditional, cVchTotal, sVchStatus,
                COALESCE(κωδικος, '') AS sVchSubCode, sfVchBelongsTo, cVchInsAmount, nfVchJob, sUsrName
            FROM Jobs
            INNER JOIN Users ON nfJobUser = nkUsr
            INNER JOIN Vouchers ON nfVchJob = nkJob
            LEFT JOIN _ΠΕΛΑΤΕΣ_ΚΕΝΤΡΑ_ΧΡΕΩΣΗΣ ON sVchSubCode = Περιγραφη AND Πελατης = sUsrClientCode
            WHERE nfVchLinkedTo IS NULL AND
            sUsrClientCode = @sUsrClientCode AND
            (@dFr IS NULL OR dJob >= @dFr) AND
            (@dTo IS NULL OR dJob <= @dTo) AND
            (@sVchSerial IS NULL OR sVchSerial LIKE (@sVchSerial + '%')) AND
            (@sConName IS NULL OR sVchConName LIKE (@sConName + '%')) AND
            (@sJobOrderId IS NULL OR sJobOrderId LIKE (@sJobOrderId + '%')) AND
            (@sUsrName IS NULL OR sUsrName = @sUsrName) AND
            (@bJobClosed IS NULL OR bJobClosed = @bJobClosed) AND
            (@bJobCanceled IS NULL OR bJobCanceled = @bJobCanceled)
            ORDER BY 1, nkJob
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs
        INNER JOIN Users ON nfJobUser = nkUsr
        INNER JOIN Vouchers ON nfVchJob = nkJob
        WHERE nfVchLinkedTo IS NULL AND
        sUsrClientCode = @sUsrClientCode AND
        (@dFr IS NULL OR dJob >= @dFr) AND
        (@dTo IS NULL OR dJob <= @dTo) AND
        (@sVchSerial IS NULL OR sVchSerial LIKE (@sVchSerial + '%')) AND
        (@sConName IS NULL OR sVchConName LIKE (@sConName + '%')) AND
        (@sJobOrderId IS NULL OR sJobOrderId LIKE (@sJobOrderId + '%')) AND
        (@sUsrName IS NULL OR sUsrName = @sUsrName) AND
        (@bJobClosed IS NULL OR bJobClosed = @bJobClosed) AND
        (@bJobCanceled IS NULL OR bJobCanceled = @bJobCanceled)
    END
END
```

I found a similar question, but with no answer:
[Asp.Net Gives a Timeout Error While Running a Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835596/asp-net-gives-a-timeout-error-while-running-a-stored-procedure)

Here is the code:

```
SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("GetVoucherJobs");
SqlConnection oConnection;
Result eResult = OpenConnection(out oConnection);
if(eResult != Result.Ok) return new GetJobsResult { eResult = eResult };

oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sUsrClientCode", oParams.ClientCode);
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dFr", oParams.DateFrom == Utils.dNull ? Utils.dNull : oParams.DateFrom);
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dTo", oParams.DateTo == Utils.dNull ? DateTime.MaxValue : oParams.DateTo);
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@sVchSerial", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if(oParams.VoucherNumber != "") oCommand.Parameters["@sVchSerial"].Value = oParams.VoucherNumber;
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@sConName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if(oParams.ConsigneeName != "") oCommand.Parameters["@sConName"].Value = oParams.ConsigneeName;
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@sUsrName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if(oParams.UserName != "") oCommand.Parameters["@sUsrName"].Value = oParams.UserName;
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@sJobOrderId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if(oParams.OrderId != "") oCommand.Parameters["@sJobOrderId"].Value = oParams.OrderId;
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@bJobClosed", SqlDbType.Bit);
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@bJobCanceled", SqlDbType.Bit);
if(oParams.State != VoucherState.All) {
    oCommand.Parameters["@bJobClosed"].Value = oParams.State == VoucherState.Open ? 0 : 1;
    if(oParams.State == VoucherState.ClosedActive || oParams.State == VoucherState.ClosedCanceled) {
        oCommand.Parameters["@bJobCanceled"].Value = oParams.State == VoucherState.ClosedActive ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bGTCostCenter", oParams.UseGTCostCenter);
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("bCount", 0);

SqlDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: A couple of things to try: 1) Make your stored procedure RETURN straight away; if the call from ado.net still times out then you know something extremely fishy is going on. If that is the case then ensure sql server 2005 is patched with the latest service packs (or try it with sql server 2008 express) - I have seen this behaviour before (on sql 2000 tho)

Comment: please show the code you use to call the procedure

Comment: @wal I'll restore the production db to a local copy and hope I get the same results, so to test the RETURN thing. Now about the service pack I'm using the latest one (sp4).

Comment: Especially if you have lots of parameter with `DBNull.Value`, I would **NOT** use `.AddWithvalue`. Doing this forces ADO.NET to **guess** what the parameter type will be - kinda hard if you pass in a NULL..... use **explicit** construction of parameters where you **specify** the datatype!

Comment: And pass DBNull.Value to them afterwards? Or just add them? (Why you removed SQL Server highlighting?)

Comment: Do you provide ConnectionTimeout value for your connection? If you do try using SQL Server profiler to see why the query takes that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get different results from Management Studio, it may be that some of your connection settings are different - e.g. ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING.

Try setting them explicitly in your SP - this may help you get the same behavior in Management Studio and .NET, which will help with your diagnosis.

Comment: You are right! Show it before here,
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1304/reproducing-sql-server-query-execution-plan-performance-problems/

but I was sure it wasn't that. It turns out that with the same settings, management studio take a lot to finish. This does not solve my problem, but at least I know where to look. Thanks!

Comment: When I set arithabort on it finishes immediately. So I just have to find out where an overflow occurs.

Comment: Eventually the problem is caused because of parameter sniffing
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/
I don't know why setting arithabort to on, solves the problem. My guess is that by setting the option, the stored procedures cash is cleaned and so the sp is recompiled and runs fine.